# userspecific tables with stored procedures and windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I need a procedure that gives me userspecific data from my sql server database for my visual studio programm (vb.net). Workers in the factory should only see there own timetables. I have a Table with Workers_ID and Name (The name is identically to the windows User Name in the Domain. Our secretarian put that in via another frontend). The idea is to write a paramtetric stored procedure that gives me (depending on the SUSER_NAME) the Workers_ID and then i can select other Tables by this Workers_ID (since it is the foreign key in other tables). Here is my code:

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USERTAB as
DECLARE @TEMPUSER_ID as int
declare @MyDomainLogin varchar(30)
```

`Suser_Name gives me the Domain\Username. I cut the "Domain\" part off, since i dont need it.`

```
BEGIN
SET @MyDomainlogin = SUSER_NAME()
SET @MyDomainLogin = SUBSTRING(@MyDomainLogin,CHARINDEX('\',@MyDomainLogin) + 1,30) 

SELECT @TEMPUSER_ID = Workers_ID FROM Workers
WHERE Name = @MyDomainLogin
SELECT * FROM TimeTable
WHERE Workers_ID = @TEMPUSER_ID
END

exec USERTAB
```

The Results gives me the right table but over and over again until i get the error msg:

```
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USERTAB, Line 14
```

Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Looks like a trigger i dont know... would be really really great if one of you could gimme a hand!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USERTAB as
...
END
GO -- this is missing
exec USERTAB
```

Your "exec USERTAB" is inside the stored procedure because you did not terminate the CREATE batch to show the end of the stored procedure

So, what you currently have

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USERTAB as
...
END

exec USERTAB -- this is inside the proc so it calls itself
GO -- this is the end of the batch!!!!
```